# what is the code for setting up a display window in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

So i am programming in pyqt5 at the moment, so I have constructed a widget with a grid, Which I did this manually, currently I am creating a minesweeper clone, and so I am displaying a 10 by 10 grid, (i am actively working on trying to make it so that the user can assign a grid size they'd like) so, everything is great and working and all... except I forgot to provide a window up top that displays the number of bombs inside the puzzle.

I constructed my program via hard-coding, and I did not use "designer" (for me it's just easier for me to work in the program, when it's my own I just construct it more efficiently, and etc). anyways I understand that this question may have been asked before, but for me I have a unique situation.

I just need a little window above my grid (game) that displays the number of bombs, so I understand that pyqt5 has quick hard coding options, but I do not know what the quick way to program a small window is.

here is a quick snippet of what the grid sort of layout looks like:

```
class windowm(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(windowm, self).__init__()
        self.check = 0


        widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)


        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        widget.setLayout(layout)


        self.puzzle = QLabel("X")
        font = QFont("Arial", 24, QFont.Bold)
        self.puzzle.setFont(font)
        self.puzzle.setFrameStyle(QFrame.StyledPanel | QFrame.Sunken)
        self.puzzle.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)


        self.buttons = []
        buttons = []
        used = []
        self.use = []
        self.Bombs = 0
        bombcount = 0
        bombs = 1
        bomb = "*"
        self.workfrik = []


        # grid layouts figure out what size the need to be automatically
        grid = QGridLayout()
        bombStruck = False

        menu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&Game")
        newAct = QAction("&New", self, shortcut=QKeySequence.New, triggered=self.newGame)
        menu.addAction(newAct)
        menu.addSeparator()
        quitAct = QAction("E&xit", self, shortcut=QKeySequence.Quit, triggered=self.close)
        menu.addAction(quitAct)


        self.setWindowTitle("Minesweeper")
        self.model = HangmanModel()

        self.newGame()

        gg = []
        self.use = self.workfrik


        for i in range(100):
            button = QPushButton()

        for i in range(100):
            clicker = str(i)
            button = QPushButton(clicker)
            button.setText("*")
            self.use = self.workfrik


            blin = self.getBombs(i)
            killed = '*'    

            if blin == 0:
                button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked0)
            if blin == 1:
                button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked1)
            if blin == 2:
                button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked2)
            if blin == 3:
                button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked3)                
            if blin == 4:
                button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked4)
            if blin == 10:
                button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClickedkill)
            if blin == 5:
                button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked5)
            if blin == 6:
                button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked6)
            if blin == 7:
                button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked7)                
            if blin == 8:
                button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked8)


            self.buttons.append(button)
            row = i // 10 # integer division by # of columns to get the row
            col = i % 10  # remainder when divided by # of cols gives us a column
            grid.addWidget(self.buttons[i], row, col) # note we set the location

        layout.addLayout(grid)
```

So that is the meat of my program. I have another class where it finds the number of bombs within the puzzle, and i just need to know how to quickly set up a little box above my grid without messing it up (believe me i tried and i keep getting a gui mess.)

is there any sort of short code to do it like: `QWindow("number of bombs", bombs)`and to have it look something like this:

[image]

so i have included a picture somehow into this question, so that is just an example but any sort of box that simply displays a number will work.

please and thank you! much appreciated if you help me out!
(sorry i'm new to this maybe you guys could give a few hints or tell me about the rules of this forum?)
is there any sort of quick-code way to do it? like the title code, or like the example that i just described. many thanks!

many apoligies i forgot to include all of my imports! here they are:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from modelm import *
from random import *
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
```

there, if you use this i'm pretty sure that if you have pyqt5 installed then that should fire up without problem.

Comment: So, you are asking if there's a way to "add" other widgets above the current grid layout, right?

Comment: yes i was trying to use "QLCDNumber" simply at the top of my grid, and the thing is just so stupid and it  doesn't want to work for me! sorry i am a C++ guy I recently got thrown into this, so this is different.

Comment: I should have thought about it first things first but i got carried away with constructing my program first. Sorry.

Comment: So, why don't you add those widgets to the main QVBoxLayout (`layout`) before adding the grid layout? If they are more than one, just add an QHBoxLayout to it and add those widget to that layout. Note that you can also use [`insertWidget(0, widget)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#insertWidget) if you want to add widgets later (or `insertLayout()` if you need to insert a layout).

Comment: so how would i do that? so i have a varaible lets say named bomsnum, do i have to for example #include anytihng? and can i use a variable inside it? like widget(bombsnum, widget)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what "bomsnum" has to do with it.

Comment: sorry i hit enter bc i wanted to skip a line, but it posted the comment too soon, i updated it

Comment: could you show me how to set up a quick box above my grid that can display the contents of bombsnum?

Comment: Use a QLabel and update it with `setText(str(bombsnum))` (or `setNum(bombsnum)`) whenever the bomb number changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after doing A LOT of digging around i found this code that did it for me:

```
self.newGame()
self.Bombs = bombcount
bombcount = str(bombcount)
doing = 'bombs: ' + bombcount
doing = str(doing)
self.puzzle = QLabel(doing)
font = QFont("Arial", 24, QFont.Bold)
self.puzzle.setFont(font)
self.puzzle.setFrameStyle(QFrame.StyledPanel | QFrame.Sunken)
self.puzzle.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
layout.addWidget(self.puzzle)
```

I ended up using a Qlabel like you said, but i had to concatonate doing into a string because my bombcount was an integer and it was giving me a stupid output.